# Flutter doctor hangs at "Running pub upgrade..." during windows 10 install

Tags: flutter, installation, flutter-doctor

## Problem

During the windows install process found here https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows, you need to run `flutter doctor -v`. Whenever I execute the command in an administrator Command Prompt or the flutter_console (with admin privileges) the command hangs on `Running pub upgrade`. I have waited over an hour for the command to execute with no luck. (See Pic below for results of running `flutter doctor -v` and `flutter pub upgrade --verbose`). I've installed flutter before, and the full flutter doctor installation took at most 1 min.

[IMAGE LINK: Command Prompt Output from running flutter-doctor, seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sid2K.png)

[IMAGE LINK: Command Prompt Output from running flutter-pub-upgrade --verbose, seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07rQ8.png)

Any Help is greatly appreciated,
Thank You!
I will update with solution if I find one.

## Environment

- Windows 10.0.19
- Flutter saved in c:\Dev\Flutter (Shouldn't need admin
  privileges to access).
- Located in Canada with stable internet.
- Git for windows installed.
- Setup my `flutter\bin`, `Git\bin\cmd`, `Git\bin\git.exe` and, `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` environment variables.

## What Ive Tried all ready

- Tried manual downloading flutter_windows_3.3.9-stable.
- Tried git Clone `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`.
- Tried deleting the flutter\bin\cache and re-running flutter.
- Tried using a VPN.
- Tried Rebooting in Safe Networking mode and running flutter doctor.
- Tried `flutter pub cache repair` Same problem.
- Tried just running flutter pub upgrade, Same problem.
- Tried turning off windows defender.
- Tried unzipping flutter stable download with 7-Zip and File Explorer.

Any Help is greatly appreciated,
Thank You!

Comment: Git itself seems to be working just fine, but flutter stops after finding something, or nothing, to do. It's not running another Git command. What it *is* doing, if anything, is a mystery to me.

Comment: I completely uninstalled git, flutter, VS Code and android studio then re-installed them all but still have the same problem :(